# Prove $S(1981^n) \geq 19$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, decimal-expansion

**Let $S(n)$ denote the sum of digits of a non-negative integer n. Prove that $S(1981^n) \geq 19$**

I tried to use induction. I know that $S(pq) \leq S(p)S(q)$ so $S(1981^{n+1}) \leq 19S(1981^n)$ but it leads to nowhere.

My second thought was to use $S(n) = n - 9\sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac n{10^i}\right\rfloor$ formula but I find it's useless.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the solution modulo 9? Not sure, but I think the solution might be 1 modulo 9, and it will not be 1. Maybe this kind of reasoning can be extended

Comment: Note that by the casting-out-nines rule, $S(1981^n)$ will always be exactly 1 more than a multiple of 9.  But it can never be 1 (because that's only for powers of 10).  So then you just need to prove that $S(1981^n) \ne 10$, and that will leave 19 as the minimum value it can be.

Answer (score 5):

The formula for $S(n)$ along with the fact that $1981 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ gives that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$S(1981^n)\equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$
So we just need to show that $S(1981^n)$ can never be equal to $10$. Suppose that for some $n$ we have $S(1981^n)=10$. Then
$$1981^n - 1 = \overline{d_kd_{k-1}\dots d_10}$$
with $d_k+d_{k-1}+\dots+d_1 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$. The first equality comes from the fact that $1981^n - 1$ is divisible by $10$ (since $1981\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$) while the second equivalence follows form the divisibility rule for $9$. This gives that
$$10 = S(1981^n) = \sum_{i=1}^k d_i + 1$$
so $$d_k+d_{k-1}+\dots+d_1=9 \tag{1}$$
Doing the exact same thing modulo $11$ (since $1981\equiv 1\pmod{11}$) we get $$d_k-d_{k-1}+\dots+(-1)^{k-1}d_1\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$
But from $(1)$ the only way this can happen is if
$$d_k-d_{k-1}+\dots+(-1)^{k-1}d_1=0 \tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives a contradiction since the LHS will be even while the RHS will be $9$.

Comment: Is the reason why $d_1 \neq 0$ not because $1981^n - 1$ must be even?

Comment: @L.F. Thanks for bringing it up. It was a mistake. What I meant to write is that $1981^n-1$ will always have $0$ as its last digit so it makes sense to say that adding $1$ to $1981^n-1$ will yield a digit sum of $\sum d_k + 1$.

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason I overlooked the fact that $1-1=0$ ;)